# Installing ROS2 Humble on Ubuntu Mantic

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, rosinstall, ubuntu-mantic

I got this error while trying to install ros2 humble:

```
Err:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu mantic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Reading package lists... Done                 
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu mantic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 2):

ROS 2 Humble **is not supported as a binary distribution** on Ubuntu Mantic (23.10)

In general, when you run into issues like this, it is important to check what the supported platforms are for a given ROS 2 distribution.  All of these are documented in [REP 2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html).  More specifically, in this case, you would want to consult the section for [Humble Hawksbill](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#humble-hawksbill-may-2022-may-2027).

As a rule of thumb, ROS binary packages are available for the current LTS that was available at the release of that ROS distribution.

- Crystal Clemmys (December 2018 - December 2019) - Ubuntu **Bionic** (18.04)
- Dashing Diademata (May 2019 - May 2021) - Ubuntu **Bionic** (18.04)
- Eloquent Elusor (November 2019 - November 2020) - Ubuntu **Bionic** (18.04)
- Foxy Fitzroy (May 2020 - May 2023) - Ubuntu **Focal** (20.04)
- Galactic Geochelone (May 2021 - November 2022) - Ubuntu **Focal** (20.04)
- Humble Hawksbill (May 2022 - May 2027) - Ubuntu **Jammy** (22.04)
- Iron Irwini (May 2023 - November 2024) - Ubuntu **Jammy** (22.04)
- Jazzy Jalisco (May 2024 - May 2029) - Ubuntu **Noble** (24.04)

Rolling is in the process of being migrated to **Noble** to support the Jazzy release.